# How to render different dict into Django Views

Tags: python, django, web

I've been learning django recently and I am struggling when sending over 1 dictionary into a template in Django

I have my `embedViews.py` which has multiple classes according to different sections of the page (So the `views.py` doesn't look a mess. And I can pass 1 of the classes into a template (html file) however, there is a page where I need to pass multiple dictionaries (lists) into the template. My logic told me to pass it in this way

```
rooms = {
'rooms': ev.Rooms.rooms
}

documents = {
    'docs': ev.Documents.documents
}

posts = {
    'posts': ev.Posts.posts
}
def home(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        {
        
            'rooms': rooms,
            'documents': documents,
            'posts': posts,
        }
)
```

But the home/ does not render correctly, what I am doing wrong? Couldn't find the solution in the documentation.

I expect to see all the lists on my html file. But it is showing in a strange way... Not the way I intended to look like.

[Page View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0T4o.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: Can you share how the template looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rooms =  ev.Rooms.rooms


documents =  ev.Documents.documents


posts = ev.Posts.posts
def home(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        {
        
            'rooms': rooms,
            'documents': documents,
            'posts': posts,
        }
)
```

Edit** To fix the issue, declare the `rooms` and `documents` as variables not as dictionaries.